# Why does my RegEx get two different results depending on platform?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a RegEx pattern:

```
@"((?(?!\.\d)\D)*)(\d*\.\d+|\d+)*((?(?<=\d).*))"
```

designed to break a string into 3 parts. If i have the strings

```
"asdf1234asdf"
"asdf .1234asdf"
"asdf. .1234asdf"
"asdf 12.34asdf"
"asdf123.4 asdf"
"asdf.1234asdf"
```

I need:

```
1. "asdf"     2. "1234"    3. "asdf"
1. "asdf "    2. ".1234"   3. "asdf"
1. "asdf. "   2. ".1234"   3. "asdf"
1. "asdf "    2. "12.34"   3. "asdf"
1. "asdf"     2. "123.4"   3. " asdf"
1. "asdf"     2. ".1234"   3. "asdf"
```

But depending on the platform i use, the results change.

[Regex101.com gives me the results i need](https://regex101.com/r/eJ2nM2/1)

[though in Regexstorm.com i have to modify the if statement in the Regex to a non-capturing group for it to work](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=((%3F%3A(%3F!%5C.%5Cd)%5CD)*)(%5Cd*%5C.%5Cd%2B%7C%5Cd%2B)*((%3F(%3F%3C%3D%5Cd).*))&i=asdf.%20.5345sdaf)

I.e.: I need to change it from

```
@"((?(?!\.\d)\D)*)(\d*\.\d+|\d+)*((?(?<=\d).*))"
```

to

```
@"((?:(?!\.\d)\D)*)(\d*\.\d+|\d+)*((?(?<=\d).*))"
```

to get it to work in `.NET`

So why do i need to get rid of the 'if' block? does `.NET` not support if blocks?

Comment: yes, i should add that

Comment: Did you notice that your regex101 result is using PCRE and the regexstorm one is using .NET regex?

Comment: As addition in the .NET, regular expression patterns are defined by a special syntax or language, which is compatible with Perl 5 regular expressions. Here a reference [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

Comment: Your approach is too complicated (for nothing), you can achieve the same using the split method with `@"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)"` (and if you want to check the line format, you only need to count the number of items) (works with Javascript, Python, Perl, .net, PHP ..., doesn't work with Java).

Comment: its not complicated for nothing, i have to always compare $1 against other $1 and $2 against other $2 and $3 against other $3. Splitting the string will lose the index on empty captures.

Comment: The capture can't be empty. Even if you have "abc123" or "123def", you obtain always three items.

Comment: This is really mind-blowing: a regex matching discontinuous text? Why and how come? With `first1234third`, the `((?(?!\.\d)\D*))(\d*\.?\d+)*((?(?<=\d).*))` regex captures `first` into Group 1 and `third` into *Group 2*! And Group 3 is empty. But Group 2 matches float/integer numbers, so, what is going on?

Comment: Yes. that is my problem. isn't that weird?

Comment: Use an _expressional_ conditional instead .. see my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RegEx is more similar to English than it is to C#. It's a language used to define patterns which will find matches within strings. Every language needs to implement their regular expression engine and therefore there are differences between most, while the concepts stay mostly the same. Usually, the more complicated the expression the more likely it isn't cross-platform compatible. That's why everyone will ask SO users what programming language they use when a vague RegEx question is asked.

This is why tools like [RegEx101](https://regex101.com) need to have multiple "flavors" for testing an expression thoroughly. You'll also notice the "Quick Reference" content (cheat sheet containing tokens, quantifiers, etc.) changes as you change between engines.

***Wikipedia:*** *[Comparison of regular expression engines.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines)*

Comment: As addition in the .NET, regular expression patterns are defined by a special syntax or language, which is compatible with Perl 5 regular expressions. Here a reference [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, @mijail -- I don't have much .NET experience :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously Dot-Net doesn't do assertion conditionals correctly.
I wouldn't use these type of conditionals for anything.

Dot-Net does however do *Expressional* conditionals very well.
All you have to do is wrap any group of constructs inside a conditional group.

Example:  `(?(  expressional construct ) .. | ..)`

So, putting assertion inside there works just fine.

---

***Note that Dot-Net is the only engine that supports `expressional` conditionals.

It's probably just as well that it is the only conditionals they do correctly.***

---

[Formatted:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 # @"((?((?!\.\d))\D)*)(\d*\.\d+|\d+)((?((?<=\d)).*))"

 (                             # (1 start)
      (?(
           (?! \. \d )
        )
           \D 
      )*
 )                             # (1 end)
 ( \d* \. \d+ | \d+ )          # (2)
 (                             # (3 start)
      (?(
           (?<= \d )
        )
           .* 
      )
 )                             # (3 end)
```

C#:

```
string [] sAAA = { 
    "asdf1234asdf",
    "asdf .1234asdf",
    "asdf. .1234asdf",
    "asdf 12.34asdf",
    "asdf123.4 asdf",
    "asdf.1234asdf",
    };
Regex RxAAA = new Regex(@"((?((?!\.\d))\D)*)(\d*\.\d+|\d+)((?((?<=\d)).*))");
for (int i = 0; i < sAAA.Length; i++)
{
    Match _mAAA = RxAAA.Match( sAAA[i] );
    if (_mAAA.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1. = \"{0}\", \t2. = \"{1}\", \t3. = \"{2}\"",
            _mAAA.Groups[1].Value, _mAAA.Groups[2].Value, _mAAA.Groups[3].Value );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1. = "asdf",    2. = "1234",    3. = "asdf"
1. = "asdf ",   2. = ".1234",   3. = "asdf"
1. = "asdf. ",  2. = ".1234",   3. = "asdf"
1. = "asdf ",   2. = "12.34",   3. = "asdf"
1. = "asdf",    2. = "123.4",   3. = " asdf"
1. = "asdf",    2. = ".1234",   3. = "asdf"
```